# How to make Banshee to play AAC audio streams?

Tags: banshee, aac

I have played MP3 radio with Banshee but I had to use VLC to play AAC streams.

How to make it work with Banshee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the "GStreamer plugin for aac" in the "Ubuntu Software Center"

Answer (score 0):

change the file from aac to m4a, so that music player will treat it as a different type, it works for me in Ubuntu 13.10 with clementine.

Comment: Are you suggesting conversion, or simply renaming the file. If the first, what tool do you use, if the second, simply editing a file extension is normally a bad idea.